# (Winsock TCP programming) How to determine if there is a message to be received?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

I've made a TCP Server and a client but I got stuck on a probably very simple thing.

There are two functions, "recv()" and "send()". "recv()" can return different values like "SOCKET_ERROR" (and others) that signs that connection was lost or something else.

In the server (which is threaded), a message "Connecting..." is sent when a client connects and then either "Connection successful" or "Connection failed" followed by the error. In short it can either be:

```
send(...) //Connecting...
...
send(...) //Connection successful
```

or:

```
send(...) //Connecting...
...
send(...) //Connection failed
...
send(...) //The error
```

How can I check if there is a message waiting to be received?

Comment: Have you done any research at all?

Comment: You might like to  read this: http://unpbook.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use select(...) API on socket to wait for N milliseconds to check if message is ready to be received or if send API can be executed without blocking.